Animation Access using VBA
Please can someone help, I have been working
on this for over a week!
I have a powerpoint with one slide, one shape (textbox)
containig the string "Hello There"  I set the animation
to "appear" and changed the text color (in the Dim area)
I the wrote this macro and it works!

Sub TestColorEffect01()
    Dim slide As slide
    Dim shape As shape
    Dim effect As effect
    Dim behavior As AnimationBehavior
    
    ' Reference the first slide
    Set slide = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
    
    ' Reference the first shape (assuming it's your textbox)
    Set shape = slide.Shapes(1)
    
    ' Add an animation effect to the shape (e.g., a Fade entrance)
    Set effect = slide.TimeLine.MainSequence.AddEffect(shape:=shape, effectId:=msoAnimEffectFade, trigger:=msoAnimTriggerOnPageClick)
    
    ' Add a ColorEffect behavior to the effect if it's not already there
    Set behavior = effect.Behaviors.Add(msoAnimTypeColor)
    
    ' Set color properties in the ColorEffect behavior
    If Not behavior Is Nothing Then
        behavior.ColorEffect.From.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0) ' Set start color to red
        behavior.ColorEffect.To.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 255)   ' Set end color to blue
    End If
    
    ' Print out the RGB values to check
    Debug.Print "From Color: " & behavior.ColorEffect.From.RGB
    Debug.Print "To Color: " & behavior.ColorEffect.To.RGB
    
    Call TestColorEffect02
End Sub

Sub TestColorEffect02()
    Dim slide As slide
    Dim shape As shape
    Dim effect As TimeLine
    Dim behavior As AnimationBehavior
    Dim iBehavior As Integer
    
    ' Reference the first slide
    Set slide = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
    
    ' Reference the first shape (assuming it's your textbox)
    Set shape = slide.Shapes(1)
    
    ' Add an animation effect to the shape (e.g., a Fade entrance)
    'Set effect = slide.TimeLine.MainSequence.AddEffect(shape:=shape, effectId:=msoAnimEffectFade, trigger:=msoAnimTriggerOnPageClick)
    
    ' Add a ColorEffect behavior to the effect if it's not already there
    Set behavior = slide.TimeLine.MainSequence(1).Behaviors(1)
    
    ' Set color properties in the ColorEffect behavior
    If behavior Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "bad dog"
'        behavior.ColorEffect.From.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0) ' Set start color to red
'        behavior.ColorEffect.To.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 255)   ' Set end color to blue
    End If
    
    
    ' Print out the RGB values to check
    Debug.Print "From Color: " & behavior.ColorEffect.From.RGB    '<=========== error on this line
    Debug.Print "To Color: " & behavior.ColorEffect.To.RGB        '<=========== and this line
    
    
    ' Print out the RGB values to check
    'Debug.Print "From Color: " & ActivePresentation.Slides(1).TimeLine.MainSequence(1).Behaviors(1).ColorEffect.From.RGB
    'Debug.Print "To Color: " & ActivePresentation.Slides(1).TimeLine.MainSequence(1).Behaviors(1).ColorEffect.To.RGB
    
End Sub


When i call the second macro no matter what i do i get errors on the Debug statements
     "Animation Behavior (unknown member); Invalid request
     

Does anybody have any ideas.?
Thank you for your time
Charlie

There are three behaviours - only the third one is of type msoAnimTypeColor - but you set behaviour to the first one which has type msoAnimTypeSet
So you have to iterate over all three of them to get the one with the correct animation type:
    Dim i As Long
    With slide.TimeLine.MainSequence(1)
        For i = 1 To .Behaviors.Count
            If .Behaviors(i).Type = msoAnimTypeColor Then
                Set behavior = .Behaviors(i)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End With

